# easy way to run a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've written a very easy jquery plugin based on a tutorial/template. What I wonder if there is a way to start the plugin except on a document object?

I want to run it like this: `myplugin();`

instead of this: `$('.anydiv').myplugin();`

as my plugin doesn't benefit of being run ontop of an element.

or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: well, its not really a plugin if it doesnt use that syntax, its more like a library that requires jquery

Comment: When do you want the plugin to run? Call the plugin function during that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Andreas Norman,

You have to create the plugin as the jquery plugin syntax and call the plugin as you said

```
$('.anydiv').myplugin();
```

If you really want to call like:

```
myplugin();
```

then it should be like a function

```
var myplugin = function(){ ...};

function myplugin(){...}
...
....
```

Comment: i agree with this, if it isnt used as a plugin function, dont make it a plugin function, its pretty obvious really

Comment: Dear, when you say plugin, it is not like it does more than or great than function, NO, plugin is a function, read this: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: ok thank you for your help, I understand better how it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(){
     // your code goes here.
}
```

[Source](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

**Quote** from jQuery website -

Let's say we want to create a plugin that makes text within a set of retrieved elements green. All we have to do is add a function called greenify to $.fn and it will be available just like any other jQuery object method.

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
```

If you want to enable chaining, `$(".myClass").greenify().css('color','white')` like jquery calls can usually be return a reference to the original object.

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    return this;
}

$( "a" ).greenify().addClass( "greenified" );
```